# port scanner in python

Tags: python, sockets, irc

```
  if data.find('!scan') != -1:
     nick = data.split('!')[ 0 ].replace(':','')
     targetip = gethostbyname(arg)
     sck.send('PRIVMSG ' + chan + " :" ' scanning host' + targetip + '\r\n')
     for i in range(20, 1025):
         s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
         result = s.connect_ex((targetip, i))
         if (result == 0) :
              s.send('PRIVMSG ' + chan + " :" 'port %d: OPEN' % (i,) + '\r\n')
         s.close()
```

I'm trying to code a small portscanner for my IRC bot, and I keep getting this error..

```
NameError: name 'gethostbyname' is not defined
```

Comment: I think, you import socket module as `import socket` and then trying to use functions without the `socket` prefix. Use `socket.gethostbyname`, `socket.socket`, `socket.AF_INET` or import as `from socket import *` (I prefer the first approach). It complains on `gethostbyname` because it comes earlier then `socket(AF_INET...`.

Comment: @khachik I have `sck = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)` and when I try to import as `from socket import *` I get this error `AttributeError: type object '_socketobject' has no attribute 'gethostbyname'`

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import socket
>>> socket.gethostbyname('localhost')
'127.0.0.1'
```

As mentioned make sure you imported the socket module, and depending on how you did that you can call `gethostbyname()`.

Comment: with `socket.gethostbyname()` I get this error `TypeError: gethostbyname() argument 1 must be string, not list`

Comment: OK, then you are calling the right function with the wrong argument, could you tell us what arg is when you call gethostbyname?

Comment: Try some debug printing, my friend. You're passing a list to `gethostbyname()`.

Comment: Yes, if you just `print` that argument you should clearly see it is a list. I have sometimes fallen victim to functions which return a list with only a single item, such as struct.unpack().

Answer (score 1):

At the top of your script, it's looks like you performed:

```
from socket import *
```

Or something "relatively" large that's bringing `socket` names directly into yours global namespace.

You shouldn't do that because it's bad practice and causes issues like the one you're experiencing where you're confusing `socket.socket` (the class) with `socket` (the module).  Your namespace has become muddled with everything that gets imported from the socket module, which is a lot:

```
>>> import socket
>>> len(socket.__all__)
241
```

(`__all__` being the module variable that specifies the public names for a module and dictates what gets exported when someone performs a `from x import *` on your module).

241 is a lot of distinct names to import into the global namespace (assuming that's the case) and gives you a lot of rope with which to hang yourself as far as overwriting or accidentally reusing variables that were imported from `socket`.

Answer (score 0):

`gethostbyname` should be imported from somewhere? Try `socket.gethostbyname()`, or whatever you imported `socket` as.

Comment: with `sck.gethostbyname()` I get this error `AttributeError: '_socketobject' object has no attribute 'gethostbyname'`

Comment: Yeah, I found it's a function in the socket module, try socket.gethostbyname (it works on my machine, at least).

Answer (score 0):

You can do port scans pretty easily in about 2 lines with [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#tcp-port-scanning). You can dump the DNS name of your target directly into it. If you still need the target's IP address though, remember to import `socket` before calling [`socket.gethostbyname`](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.gethostbyname).